# Is there a good batch Migration tool for migration from Firebird to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, migration, firebird

We have a lot of Firebird databases that we want to convert to MySQL. Is there any good tool out there to automate the conversion?

All databases have the same structure, and each FireBird Database should be converted into its own MySQL database.

The tools should at least be able to migrate the data (since we could copy the blank db), but creation of the MySQL db would be a plus.

Comment: Try asking on http://serverfault.com

Comment: Look here http://metadata.eu/products/fullconvert/tutorials/convert/interbase-firebird/to/mysql

Comment: You are trying to convert or migrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can test [Database Comparer](http://www.clevercomponents.com/products/dbcomparer/index.asp)

Comment: also [Interbase Data Pump](http://www.clevercomponents.com/products/datapump/index.asp)